# Get Values in Deropdown when a value is selected from another dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, xslt

My Web Page has two Dropdown list
1) Containing Book Name
2) Containing link Of the Book.
The Data is stored in form of XML File
something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookDetail>
<book>
    <bookName>Dollar Bahu</bookName>
    <link>http:\\DollarBahu.in</link>
</book>
<book>
    <bookName>The Lost Symbol</bookName>
    <link>http:\\TheLostSymbol.in</link>
</book>
<book>
    <bookName>Keep The Change</bookName>
    <link>http:\\KeepTheChange.in</link>
</book>
</BookDetail>
```

Function:
    
            window.onload=function()
            {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("GET", "bookDetails.xml", false);
                xhttp.send();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        var xml = xhttp.responseXML;
                        var books = xml.getElementsByTagName('book');
                        var book = document.getElementById('book'),
                        link = document.getElementById('link');

```
                    for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
                    {
                        var obook = document.createElement('option'),
                        olink = document.createElement('option'),
                        tbook =   document.createTextNode(books[i].children[0].innerHTML),
                        tlink =   document.createTextNode(books[i].children[1].innerHTML);

                        obook.appendChild(tbook);
                        olink.appendChild(tlink);
                        book.appendChild(obook);
                        link.appendChild(olink);
                        map[tbook] = olink;
                    }
                    var updateLink = function(e)
                    {
                        //map[e.target.value].setAttribute('selected','');
                        //alert(map[e.target.value]);
                        for (var i = 0; i< link.children.length; i++)
                        {
                            link.children[i].removeAttribute('selected');
                        }
                           link.children[this.selectedIndex].setAttribute('selected','');
                    };
                    book.addEventListener('change', updateLink, false);
                }


                //var xmlString = "<BookDetail><book>    <bookName>Dollar Bahu</bookName>    <link>http:\\DollarBahu.in</link></book><book>    <bookName>The Lost Symbol</bookName>    <link>http:\\TheLostSymbol.in</link></book><book>    <bookName>Keep The Change</bookName>    <link>http:\\KeepTheChange.in</link></book></BookDetail>";
                //var xml = ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml"),i,
                //map = {};

            }

        }
    </script>
```

I have successively inserted valus in first dropdown list containing bookName.
Now my question is how to get book link in second dropdown list of that particular bookName from XML?

Comment: What is your expected behavior? If I select Dollar Bahu in the first dropdown, http:\\DollarBahu.in should get selected in the second dropdown? or the second dropdown should only be populated with the associated links? This doesn't make much sense, since there is only one link for every book, right?

Comment: Yes,There is only one link associated with each book.
It should be If I select a Particular book(eg Dollar Bahu) in the first dropdown.Second dropdown should get selected with its associated link (i.e  http:\\DollarBahu.in)
I am able to fetch the name of book selected by the user but don't know how to use it to fetch associated link from the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete working solution:

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "book.xml");
  xhttp.send();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var books = xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('book');
        var book = document.getElementById('book'),
        link = document.getElementById('link');

        for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            var obook = document.createElement('option'),
                olink = document.createElement('option'),
                tbook = document.createTextNode(books[i].children[0].innerHTML),
                tlink = document.createTextNode(books[i].children[1].innerHTML);

            obook.appendChild(tbook);
            olink.appendChild(tlink);

            book.appendChild(obook);     
            link.appendChild(olink);      
    }
  }
}

var updateLink = function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i< link.children.length; i++) {
        link.children[i].removeAttribute('selected');
    }
    link.children[this.selectedIndex].setAttribute('selected','');
};

book.addEventListener('change', updateLink, false);
```

With this HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="book" id="book">
  </select>
  <select name="link" id="link">
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is `book.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookDetail>
<book>
    <bookName>Dollar Bahu</bookName>
    <link>http:\\DollarBahu.in</link>
</book>
<book>
    <bookName>The Lost Symbol</bookName>
    <link>http:\\TheLostSymbol.in</link>
</book>
<book>
    <bookName>Keep The Change</bookName>
    <link>http:\\KeepTheChange.in</link>
</book>
</BookDetail>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help.But what if I want to directly fetch the data from the XML file and not using xmlString and parse it.Do you have any other option? @Federico

Comment: I have updated my Function.Online First book and first link is displayed.No further data is displayed @Federico

Comment: @Rish I posted my working solution. It works without problems. Please, include more details if you still have problems.

Answer (score 1):

In the onchange event of the bookName dropdown you can retrieve the selectedIndex property, and then use that value to get the corresponding book link.

Comment: You are right, I did that .
I have the bookName that is selected by the use but don't know how to use it to retrieve the corresponding link